# Pandas: Add one column's value to another if index exists

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

A:

```
   foo   bar   foo2  
0   1     1     1      
1   2     2     2
2   3     3     3
3   3     3     3
```

B:

```
   foo
0   1
2   2
3   1 
4   5
```

I would like to add up values of B whose index exists in A to a column of A (on the row with corresponding index) WITHOUT
values from B which have no corresponding index in A being added or removing indices not present in both A and B:

```
   foo   bar   foo2  
0   2     1     1      
1   2     2     2
2   5     3     3
3   6     3     3
```

I feel like this should be straight forward but using `add` and `concat` I end up with either not all rows from A or a union of A and B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, straightforward, and efficient - use set operations to get the intersection of the indices, then perform `loc` based arithmetic -

```
i = A.index.intersection(B.index)
j = A.columns.intersection(B.columns)

A.loc[i, j] += B.loc[i, j]
```

```
A
   foo  bar  foo2
0    2    1     1
1    2    2     2
2    5    3     3
3    4    3     3
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `add` with `fill_value=0`, you also need `dropna` at the end

```
A.add(B,fill_value=0).dropna().astype(int)
Out[434]: 
   bar  foo  foo2
0    1    2     1
1    2    2     2
2    3    5     3
3    3    4     3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
A["foo"] = (A["foo"] + B["foo"]).fillna(A["foo"])
```

Answer (score 0):

One other option may be as:

```
result_df = (A + B).fillna(A).dropna()
print(result_df)
```

Result:

```
   bar  foo  foo2
0  1.0  2.0   1.0
1  2.0  2.0   2.0
2  3.0  5.0   3.0
3  3.0  4.0   3.0
```